# Using Google Drive API To download files

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-authentication

I have used the Google API to download files from Google drive but unfortunately I faced a problem which is *access to the path 'Daimto.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store' is denied*. I do not know how to solve this problem and I do not know I am using  the correct parameters in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() method.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
  using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
  using System.Threading;
  using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
  using Google.Apis.Services;
  using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  namespace DownloadFromGoogleDrive
  {
      public partial class _Default : Page
      {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              //Scopes for use with the Google Drive API
              string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                   DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
              // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
              UserCredential credential =
                          GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
                                        .AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                                        {
                                            ClientId = "581284671387-uqf7v4ci6olktjthppd590uv8vnaqvc0.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                                        ,
                                            ClientSecret = "eZZd5zTThgKroNClKDKWR-mJ"
                                        }
                                                        , scopes
                                                        , Environment.UserName
                                                        , CancellationToken.None
                                                        , new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")
                                                        ).Result;

              DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
              {
                  HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                  ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
              });


          }

          /// <summary>
          /// Download a file
          /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
          /// </summary>
          /// <param name="_service">a Valid authenticated DriveService</param>
          /// <param name="_fileResource">File resource of the file to download</param>
          /// <param name="_saveTo">location of where to save the file including the file name to save it as.</param>
          /// <returns></returns>
          public static Boolean downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
          {

              if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
              {
                  try
                  {
                      var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl);
                      byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
                      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
                      return true;
                  }
                  catch (Exception e)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                  return false;
              }
          }

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

FileDataStore stores your authentication information in the %AppData% directory.

So what you end up with is something like this

```
C:\Users\linda_l\AppData\Roaming\Daimto.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store
```

You need to ensure that the process running the application has access to the %AppData% directory or create your own implementation of Idatastore to store the file someplace else say current directory [LocalFileDataStore.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Authentication/Diamto.Google.Authentication/Diamto.Google.Authentication/LocalFileDataStore%20.cs)

you can find a tutorial explaining this in more detail here. [Google Oauth2 C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/)